# Update XML On WebServer - AppleScript Curl

Tags: xml, applescript

I have an XML stored at the URL.

```
http://192.168.10.5:8008/GetUserVars
```

This returns the following structure.

```
<BrightSignUserVariables>
<BrightSignVar name="CurrentLetter">v</BrightSignVar>
<BrightSignVar name="CurrentUserEmail">bob@email.com</BrightSignVar>
<BrightSignVar name="CurrentUserName">bob</BrightSignVar>
</BrightSignUserVariables>
```

I used the following to parse the XML to get the value of the variables.

```
set userVars to do shell script "curl -X GET 'http://192.168.10.5:8008/GetUserVars'"

tell application id "com.apple.SystemEvents"
    tell (make new XML data with data userVars)
        tell XML element "BrightSignUserVariables"
            tell (every XML element whose name = "BrightSignVar") to ¬
                set {CurrentLetter, CurrentEmail, CurrentName} to its value
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

This works fine but now I want to update one of the variable and Post back to the URL
eg

```
set value of XML element "CurrentUserName" to "Andrew"
```

I've tried inserting this above the "end tell" statements not sure if that's correct.
Also struggling to post back to the URL (should this use curl??)

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK _System Events_ can read but not edit XML. However macOS ships with the [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html) command line [XSLT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT)  processor. Consider _"shelling out"_ from AppleScript to transform your XML using an XSLT Template. This [example gist](https://paste.ee/p/1czfe) currently writes your desired result to a file on your _Desktop_ named `result.xml`. Regarding posting back to the URL, that's going to depend on your webserver config (more details needed !). You may want to firstly try using `curl`'s `POST` method.

Comment: What's unclear from your question, (and therefore what makes it difficult to provide a solution/answer regarding posting back to the URL), is... Does a `.xml` file reside at the endpoint `http://192.168.10.5:8008/GetUserVars`, i.e. is it case of simply overwriting an existing xml file? Or, (which is probably more likely) does that endpoint invoke a function server side, and the XML response that that you receive is the result of calling that function? in which case your server may provide some other function/method for updating and therefore it's not a case of overwriting a `.xml` file.

Comment: Hi server side there is a .xml file (I believe) which just needs updating.  I have tried using curl post (for the first time) however get errors , probably because I am not scripting it correctly.  Can’t give example script as on mobile.  Do you have a quick example of how curl post should be written